# Bootstrap carousel: run a jquery function upon slide change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need to run this function:

```
$("#wrap").animate({
    backgroundPositionX: '+=50%'
},0);
```

upon Bootstrap carousel slide change. Also it is important if it slides to next or prev. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the slide event with this:

```
.on('slide', function (e) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: thanks, but what about a direction? ( i mean if it slides to next or back)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430119/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-get-the-direction-of-slide