# Bootstrap carousel - different directions for each slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a typical twitter bootstrap carousel with 4 images. I want to change the slide direction in such a way that the first image slides left, the second slides up, the third slides down and the last one slides right. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can find a solution by the following link

(<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430119/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-get-the-direction-of-slide>)

Comment: Thank you!but that doesn't help with sliding vertically!